# How to requeue or reject in RabbitListenerErrorHandler on MANUAL ack mode?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

i'm trying to reject message in RabbitListenerErrorHandler by throwing AmqpRejextAndDontRequeueException.

But it's not working in MANUAL ack mode.(in AUTO ack mode work fine).

How can i reject message in RabbitListenerErrorHander with MANUAL ack mode??

```
public class RabbitListenerExceptionHandler implements RabbitListenerErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message amqpMessage, org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception)
        throws Exception {
        log.error("RabbitListenerHandler " + exception.getMessage() + "|" + exception.getFailedMessage());
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("reject");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using MANUAL ack mode, the listener is responsible for ack/nack; the container won't react to any exceptions thrown.

Unfortunately, the channel is currently not available in the error handler so you would have to catch the error in your listener to ack or nack the message.

I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1012) to resolve this.